# Set MS Band Tile in BackgroundTask

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task, microsoft-band

I've come across the scenario of which I can not create a WriteableBitmap in a BackgroundTask, therefore I'm unable to set the ME tile of the MS Band in the background.

Numerous forum posts have led me to a XamlRenderingBackgroundTask, is this still recommended to be done in C++, even in UWP?

As of now I'm simply trying to change my current BackgroundTask to inherit from XamlRenderingBackgroundTask, instead of IBackgroundTask.

This causes the BackgroundTask to not run at all:
The program '[1320] backgroundTaskHost.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, had to change this:

> public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)

To this:

> protected async override void OnRun(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)